# Want to show percentage data in legends of google pie chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google charts API specifically pie chart in my code i want to show percentage which is displayed inside chart to the legends also [image]

> How can i display 29.2% sleep in legend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this two ways; either set the formatted values of the labels in the DataTable to include the percents, eg:

```
// assume sleep is row 4, "sleepPercent" is the percent for sleep
data.setFormattedValue(4, 0, data.getValue(4, 0) + ' (' + (sleepPercent * 100).toFixed(1) + '%)');
```

or you can set the `legend.position` option to "labeled", which changes the way the legend is drawn, but adds the percents to the labels:

```
legend: {
    position: 'labeled'
}
```

see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Su6TX/

Answer (score 1):

**Try this for all values:**

```
var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            total = total + data.getValue(i, 1);    
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            var label = data.getValue(i, 0);
        var val = data.getValue(i, 1) ;
        var percentual = ((val / total) * 100).toFixed(1); 
        data.setFormattedValue(i, 0, label  + '- '+val +' ('+ percentual + '%)');    
    }
```