# Show values on google piechart legends

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, google-pie-chart

I have this google piechart, which is working fine, except on the legend text along with it, I wanna show the percentage and numbers. The below would be the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var options = {
            title: 'Registration',
            legend: { position: 'right', textStyle: { color: 'blue', fontSize: 16 } }
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "adminrep.aspx/GetChartData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#chart")[0]);
                chart.draw(data, options);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; margin-top:60px;"></div>
```

How do I get this done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178029/want-to-show-percentage-data-in-legends-of-google-pie-chart

Comment: @IronGeek I've seen that post and the solution given there is not viable for me. I want to get this done with having the legend position: right

Comment: the post's answer gave two solution. The second solution requires you to set the `legend.position` option to `'labeled'`, while the first solution using `setFormattedValue` does not. I think this could be applied to your problem.

Comment: @IronGeek setFormattedValue only helps with the format of how you show the values on hover. It doesn't help with showing the values with the legend. If it works, then please post an answer with working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.setFormattedValue` to format the the labels in the `DataTable`.
This still requires you do a little bit of manual calculation for the getting the total sum of values, but it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var options = {
      title: 'Registration',
      legend: { 
        position: 'right', 
        textStyle: { color: 'blue', fontSize: 16 } 
      }
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {
        json: JSON.stringify({ 
          d: [
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Work',     11],
            ['Eat',      2],
            ['Commute',  2],
            ['Watch TV', 2],
            ['Sleep',    7]
          ]}) 
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var data   = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);                
            var count  = data.getNumberOfRows();
            var values = Array(count).fill().map(function(v, i) {
              return data.getValue(i, 1);
            });
            var total =  google.visualization.data.sum(values);
            values.forEach(function(v, i) {                                         
              var key = data.getValue(i, 0);
              var val = data.getValue(i, 1);
              data.setFormattedValue(i, 0, key + ' (' + (val/total * 100).toFixed(1) + '%)');                  
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#chart")[0]);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
  }
</script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; margin-top:60px;"></div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cn74tvmL/show

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is it possible to add the values along with the percentage?

Comment: Yes. Just edit the `data.setFormattedValue()` line and include the values in the format...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [number format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter):

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,### MW'});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

or:

```
chart1.options = {
    .
    .
    .
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    legend: {
        position: 'labeled',
        labeledValueText: 'both',
        textStyle: {
            color: 'blue', 
            fontSize: 14
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Using position: labeled will leave off some datas if there are too many to render. I need to find a way to show percentage and number with having the legends position: right